# Launch shell command from PHP

Tags: php, linux, shell

Okay, this is going to be a very weird request/question.

There is a very long running PHP script that needs to be launched by the user (admin) who is not very technically adept. When running the script through apache, it throws a timeout (502 or 504 Bad Gateway).

Let's just assume that apache can't be configured to fix the timeout issues.

I want to create a button in the admin panel that sends an AJAX call to a PHP script on the server, that PHP script will act as a proxy of sorts to launch a shell command. The shell command will then execute the long running PHP script with certain arguments... but I don't want it to wait for the long running script to finish. The proxy PHP script can exit and return true/false based on if the shell command actually started (this part is optional).

Essentially, have PHP launch a shell command which launches a PHP script.

How can I pull something like this off?

Comment: This isn't a weird question... it's actually quite common and has been asked here many times before.  The real question is though... what all can you do on this server?  You might find that Cron jobs are best for certain things that need to occur at regular intervals.  Also, there are job queuing methods you can utilize if needed.  What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: I have full root access to the server. I know about cron job and have a few already setup that do other tasks. This task however depends on user action. I'm trying to run a huge insert/update on some opencart products over 100,000 records. The queries are all optimized already, there's just a lot of them in sequence.

Comment: I would set up a job queue table in your database, and add a row when the user schedules the job.  Have a cron job that runs every minute or so to kick off the job.  Then, it can update its status in that database for the user to see as well.  There are other queueing systems available, and you could even use some pub/sub, but for simple things, a cron job to start the jobs works well.

Comment: That's actually a pretty elegant solution to my issue. Since I'm sure I would have run into permissions issues when running shell commands from PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `shell_exec`. It worked for me...
http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php